# How do i dynamicly create tkinter buttons based on the number of csv file entries

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I'm making an application that will automatically add text to your clipboard. In an effort to make it more dynamic I'm trying to make the text that is copied be in a CSV file. So far I've managed to get the CSV file to import and pull data from it however when I try to add the test to my clipboard I only get the text from the last button made.

here is my CSV file (script.csv)

```
idnum,name,script
0,testone,This is a test
1,testtwo,I hope it works
2,testthree,This better work
3,testfour,Please work
```

Then here is my python program

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import csv
idnum = []
name = []
script = []

for d in csv.DictReader(open('script.csv')):
     idnum.append((d['idnum']))
     name.append((d['name']))
     script.append((d['script']))

 def add_to_clipboard(li):
     r = Tk()
     r.withdraw()
     r.clipboard_clear()
     r.clipboard_append(li)
     r.update() # now it stays on the clipboard after the window is closed
     r.destroy()
     print (li)

 root = tk.Tk()
 frame = tk.Frame(root)
 frame.pack()

 for i in idnum:
     i = int(i)

     Button(frame, text = name[i], command=lambda : add_to_clipboard(script[i])).pack()


 root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda function will evaluate the expression `script[i]` and with `i` being the last `idnum`, set by the for loop, the expression will be evaluated to: `Please work`. You have to make sure the variable i is passed as a constant instead:

```
command=lambda i=i: add_to_clipboard(script[i])
```

The `i=i` is the usual way of doing this.